# Renderer YUV frames in openGLES without CADisplayLink

Tags: ios, opengl-es, avfoundation

On my iOS app, I'm using `AVAssetReader` to decode a local MP4 file and `openGLES` to renderer each YUV420 frames. I'm using the presentation timestamp to drive the playback at the proper frame rate. What it's not clear to me is if I should use `CADisplayLink` callback to know when a frame should be displayed (always observing the PTS) or if it's okay to don't use it and have instead a secondary thread that simply pulls the decoded images and renders them via `openGLES`. I have experimented both solutions and both seem to work (at least to my eyes). Also the time it takes to display a YUV frame in both case seems to be about the same ~2-3ms. So what is the deal with `CADisplayLink`? it seems not to be necessary but it's recommended...I don't understand. Can some one explain to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CADisplayLink synchronizes OpenGL drawing with display refresh to help avoid screen tearing.  It's not required, but is recommended since it's possible with NSTimer you may experience screen tearing.  Ultimately the PTS is never really going to be the precise time the user's eyeball sees the image, but certainly it would be better to have a little bit of incongruity with the display time than potentially having two different frames on the screen at once.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This made me realize that although in my app I don't have an explicit NSTimer, the fact that I'm using the PTS to drive the playback by waiting the difference between two consecutive PTS's before display the frame, it basically acts like a timer that (like you said) might not be synchronized with the screen refresh rate. I'm now using CADisplayLink